# Per executable UDP port redirection possible?

Tags: networking, udp

I have a black box program which listens on a particular UDP port. I'd like it to listen to a UDP port of my choosing.

Is there a way to trick the executable into listening on a differen port. I might imagine there exists a library which could be injected with LD_PRELOAD that might incercept the system calls and facilitate this.

A virtual machine of course is the heavy handed option, but that's not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tell the black-box program to listen only on a specific IP address, you could bind it to an arbitrary loopback address, like 127.0.0.10, and then use netcat, AKA, `nc`, to pipe between the port on 127.0.0.10 and whatever you like on the outside IP.

There's an article on Netcat in wikipedia with a section about proxying.  You'll want to understand that and to know that the -u option lets you use UDP instead of the default, TCP.

In this example, 192.168.200.200 is the outside IP, 12345 is the port you *want* the black box to listen on.  127.0.0.10 is the IP you told the blackbox to use and 987 is the port the box rudely insists upon using.

```
mkfifo backpipe
chmod {something sane backpipe}
nc -l -u 192.168.200.200 12345 0<backpipe | nc 127.0.0.10 987 1>backpipe
```

If you don't have `mkfifo` on your system, google "mknod pipe"